# If the dot matches all ASCII characters except newline and \n matches newline, why doesn't `"a\r\nb".match(/a(.|\n)*b/)` match?

Tags: javascript, regex

This gives a `null` on Chrome or NodeJS:

```js
console.log("a\r\nb".match(/a(.|\n)*b/));
```

The `(.|\n)*` should mean "any ASCII character including newline, and any number of them: 0 or more).

Comment: `.` does not match `\r`, CR, in JS regex. Never use `(.|\n)*`. Only `[^]` or `[\s\S]`, etc.

Comment: so `.` matches all ASCII characters except newline is not true either.... I am surprised somebody has `[^]` and `[\s\S]` at the tip of their tongue

Comment: [More exactly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#Types), "Matches any single character except line terminators: `\n`, `\r`, `\u2028`  or `\u2029`".

Comment: that's why there is a saying... one mountain always higher than another mountain... but aren't I glad I am in CS...

Comment: @nopole, I think something is lost in the translation

Comment: @JoelFan because there are people who knows `.` doesn't match a newline, and then there are people who thought `(.|\n)` will do the job, and then there are people who know it doesn't and `[^]` and `[\s\S]` does... and then there are people who know exactly `.` doesn't match newline but also `\r`, `\u2028` or `\u2029`

Comment: It's about engines peculiarities e.g. `.` matches `\r` in PCRE by default (and the behavior is modifiable at runtime) but JS doesn't behave the same. Hence `any ASCII character including newline...` is not a precise definition.

Comment: @revo `.` is any ASCII character excluding newline for PCRE and any ASCII character except `\n` and `\r` for JS then

Comment: @nopole You're still missing `\u2028` and `\u2029`. I linked the exact definition from MDN, which is generallly a good source.